# Call to Stash embed being evaluated inside a Switchee statement when it shouldn't be

Tags: stash

I have a problem with a Stash embedded template being called when it's inside a switch statement (or a conditional, already tried that too) which should evaluate as false.

For example:

```
{exp:switchee variable="{stash:_nav_active}" parse="inward"}

    {case value="home|404"}{/case}

    {case default="Yes"}

        {stash:embed
            name="partials:nav:{segment_1}"
            process="start"
        }

    {/case}

{/exp:switchee}
```

even when `stash:_nav_active` equals 404, the embed is being called and because the segment doesn't exist, I get:

> Stash: the file "/stash_templates/partials/nav/made-up-segment.html" was not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think since your stash embed is set to process on 'start' it will be run first before switchee, which is why you'd see a 'file not found' error if there's no stash file at that location. Try changing your embed to process="inline" and see if you still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure I recall that if you're evaluating a stash variable you can remove the square brackets.

```
variable="stash:my_var" parse="inward"
```

Comment: Gave that a go, but got the same result.